# Отключить назначение роли пользователя при переходе по URL

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Есть сайт на WordPress. У меня есть функция: назначить роль `n_course2` если пользователь перешел по URL `site.com/c1-projden`

```
add_action('wp', 'add_new_role_2', 10, 2);
function add_new_role_2() {
       global $wp;
       $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
       if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_slug == 'c1-projden') {
                $u = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
                $u->set_role( 'n_course2' );
       }
}
```

Как отключить эту функцию (или перестать назначать роль), если URL `site.com/c1-projden` в определенный промежуток времени редиректит на другую страницу?

Comment: Не "отключить" и не "перестать назначать", а опять *назначить* (нужную) и всё станет на свои места

Comment: @SeVlad У меня есть роль пользователя, для которого на страницу site.com/c1-projden стоит редирект (не пускает). Но когда он на них заходит, ему все ровно назначается роль. А этого происходить не должно.

Comment: На каком экшене вы делаете редирект?

Comment: @DarthKYL я делаю через плагин Content Control

Comment: @АннаМатвеева этот плагин делать редирект на экшене template_redirect, поэтому вам нужно пересмотреть логику назначения роли пользователям либо изменить логику редиректов

Comment: @DarthKYL Спасибо за совет. Скажите, а можно сделать, что то вроде если пользователь находится на странице 2 секунды, то ему назначается роль? ))

Comment: @АннаМатвеева вы можете сделать назначение роли через ajax, возможно я немного позже скину пример если вам нужно

Comment: @DarthKYL Пожалуйста скиньте, буду ждать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример того как вы можете назначить пользователю который перешел на эту страницу роль через ajax после того как он начнет скролить страницу (js ивент можно заменить на любой другой). Так же это будет работать если пользователь авторизированный и у него еще нет такой роли. Для пользователей с ролью администратор я думаю не стоит присваивать эту роль поэтому ajax для них не выполняется. Так же я бы хотел обратить ваше внимание на то что метод `set_user_role` перезапишет текущие роли пользователя, возможно лучшим вариантом будет использовать `add_user_role` что бы добавить к текущей роли еще одну

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_setting_user_role_script' );

function add_setting_user_role_script() {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_name !== 'c1-projden' || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array( 'n_course2', (array) $user->roles ) || current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            let setRoleAction = false;

            $( document ).on( 'scroll', function() {
                if ( setRoleAction ) {
                    return;
                }

                let data = {
                    action: 'set_user_role',
                    nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'role_nonce' ); ?>',
                };

                setRoleAction = true;

                $.post( '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>' , data, function( response ) {
                    if ( response.success ) {
                        console.log( response.data );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>

    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_user_role', 'wp_ajax_set_user_role_callback' );

function wp_ajax_set_user_role_callback() {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'role_nonce' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Nonce not valid' );
    }

    $current_user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
    $current_user->set_role( 'n_course2' );

    wp_send_json_success( 'Set role success' );
}
```

Comment: Вставил ваш код. Все ровно работает замена роли при редиректе

Comment: @АннаМатвеева я обновил код в ответе

Comment: к сожалению не работает и он (

Comment: Вы отключили свой функционал назначения роли?

Comment: Да, заменила ваш на мой

Comment: Вы уверенны что больше нигде нет кода который присваивает пользователям эту роль?

Comment: Да ( теперь не присваевается роль и когда есть редирект, и когда его нет.

Comment: Аякс событие из моего примера срабатывает после того как пользователь начинает скролить страницу, вы можете изменить его на другое

Comment: Если бы я знала как...

Comment: Можно заменить $( document ).on( 'scroll'  на $( window ).on( 'load'

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня не получается сделать две таких функций. Это возможно? c1-projden и c2-projden и n_course2 и n_course3

Comment: можно кончено, но я бы в этом случае изменил логику присваивания роли пользователей, чтобы не дублировать код

Comment: Не могли бы показать пример, дублированного кода? Мне так проще. Я когда пытаюсь продублировать, перестает работать и первый и второй и третий и тд.

Comment: вам всего лишь нужно сделать функции уникальными, и заменить наименования ролей и названий страниц, не могу написать дублированный код это выше моих сил)))